# Camunda BPMN http-connector POST taskId

Tags: bpmn, camunda

I created a BPMN using the Camunda BPMN Modeler. Now I have a `Service-Task` with an `BPMN-Error`:

[image]

The `Service-Task` should call a REST-API using the `http-connector`. Sending the request the `TaskId` needs also to be send so that I can call the BPMN-Error-Rest-Url in case of errors.

How do I configure the BPMN to send the TaskId as Query-Parameter in the URL respectively what is the correkt taskId-Expression-Key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
http://www.my-apid.de?taskId=${execution.activityInstanceId}
```